FFmpeg scale filter unexpectedly adds padding
I'm using FFmpeg to transcode and shrink some videos to AV1 using the scale filter and AMD's hardware encoder, available in FFmpeg as av1_amf. Usually it works fine, but now I've run into a video where applying the scale filter is adding rows/columns of black pixels at the bottom/right of the video.
My test video is 854x480, with the content pillarboxed from 4:3 to occupy 16:9, and I was attempting to crop the black bars and scale it to a height of 360. Using -filter:v "crop=640:480,scale=-1:360", the output is reported as 480x360 during transcoding:
Stream #0:0(und): Video: av1 (AV01 / 0x31305641), yuv420p(tv, progressive), 480x360 [SAR 1:1 DAR 4:3], q=2-31, 2000 kb/s, 23.98 fps, 1k tbn (default)

But FFprobe on the resulting file says it's now 512x362, and there are now rows and columns of black pixels padding the bottom and right of the frame:
Stream #0:0: Video: av1 (Main), yuv420p(tv, bt709, progressive), 512x362, SAR 1:1 DAR 256:181, 23.98 fps, 23.98 tbr, 1k tbn (default)

The result is the exact same even if I add an extra crop filter at the end with "crop=640:480,scale=-1:360,crop=480:360:0:0": a video that reports as 480x360 during transcoding but ends up as 512x362. I can't seem to get rid of the padding that scale adds.
Simplifying the issue to just the scale filter, I tried a filter of nothing but scale=-1:360. This fails, with "Error submitting video frame to the encoder" - perhaps that's indicative of a problem with the input video, but "unknown error" doesn't give me much to go on. Anyway, I specify scale=640:360 and that succeeds. During transcoding, the output is reported as 640x360:
Stream #0:0(und): Video: av1 (AV01 / 0x31305641), yuv420p(tv, progressive), 640x360 [SAR 1281:1280 DAR 427:240], q=2-31, 2000 kb/s, 23.98 fps, 1k tbn (default)

But checking afterward with FFprobe, the dimensions are reported as 640x362, and there are now 2 rows of black pixels padding the bottom of the frame:
Stream #0:0: Video: av1 (Main), yuv420p(tv, bt709, progressive), 640x362, SAR 1281:1280 DAR 1281:724, 23.98 fps, 23.98 tbr, 1k tbn (default)

If I set the filter to nothing but scale=0:0, which should scale the video to its original dimensions, it's reported as 854x480 during transcoding:
Stream #0:0(und): Video: av1 (AV01 / 0x31305641), yuv420p(progressive), 854x480 [SAR 1:1 DAR 427:240], q=2-31, 2000 kb/s, 23.98 fps, 1k tbn (default)

But FFprobe says it's now 896x480, and there are now 42 columns of black pixels padding the right of the frame:
Stream #0:0: Video: av1 (Main), yuv420p(tv, bt709, progressive), 896x480, SAR 1:1 DAR 28:15, 23.98 fps, 23.98 tbr, 1k tbn (default)

The problem does not occur when using other encoders, like x264 or libsvtav1. But this is the first time I've seen av1_amf do it. What could be causing this?

It appears your AMD encoder wants frame width & height to be a multiple of 64 and 16 respectively. You haven't shown your full transcode command so can't help further.

Width needing to be a multiple of 64 fits what I'm seeing, but why would it change 360 to 362?
